# How to avoid radio button deselected automatically.

Tags: jquery

There are two radio button. when select any radio button its automatically deselected.

Following are the snippet which is not working properly.

```js
$('.radio_pmt').click(function(){
alert('click'); 
var payment_mode =$(this).attr('ownid');

 var type = typeof payment_mode;
 if(payment_mode == 'undefined' | payment_mode == null){
  alert("Please select payment method");
 }
 else
 {
  if(payment_mode == "paypal")
  {
   $('input:radio[name="payment_mode"][ownid="paypal"]').attr('checked', true);
   $('input:radio[name="payment_mode"][ownid="paypal"]').val('paypal');
   $("#paypal_form").submit();
  }
  else
  {
   $('input:radio[name="payment_mode"][ownid="braintree"]').val('braintree');
   $('input:radio[name="payment_mode"][ownid="braintree"]').attr('checked');
   $("#braintree_details").slideDown("slow"); 
   
  }
 }
 return false;
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="frm_choose_plan" name="frm_choose_plan">
<label>Choose Payment method:</label>
<input type="radio" class="radio_pmt" ownid="paypal" name="payment_mode" value="Paypal">Paypal
<input type="radio" class="radio_pmt" ownid="braintree"  name="payment_mode" value="braintree" id="credit_cardpmt">Credit card
</form>
```

Comment: remove the `return false;` line. also when using radio button it is better to use change event

Comment: @guradio : You are right...

Comment: @guradio : add your suggestion in answer so you will get credit for this solution..

Comment: @guradio - I would never use the change event on radios. It may trigger on off change too and in some browsers on blur only. We only want to capture the click event

Comment: @DiniZx i wll put it in answer mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `return false;` line and your code will work. It is deselecting because you are preventing the default action of radio button

Comment: Ah, converting the comment to answer. I see it now

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem was the "return false" which prevents the default event.

**My Suggestion**

```js
$('.radio_pmt').click(function(){
  var $input = $(this);
  var inputType = $input.attr('ownid');
  
  if (inputType === 'paypal') {
     // do something if user clicked on paypal
      
     // your code
     $("#paypal_form").submit();
    
     $('#test').html('clicked paypal'); // remove this on live page
  }
  else if (inputType === 'braintree') {
     // do something if user clicked on baintree
     $("#braintree_details").slideDown("slow");
    
     $('#test').html('clicked Credit Card'); // remove this on live page
  }
  else {
    // nothing choosed! But i cant be reached because you choose the ".radio_pmt" selector to bind your click event which has both the "ownid"
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="frm_choose_plan" name="frm_choose_plan">
<label>Choose Payment method:</label>
<input type="radio" class="radio_pmt" ownid="paypal" name="payment_mode" value="Paypal">Paypal
<input type="radio" class="radio_pmt" ownid="braintree"  name="payment_mode" value="braintree" id="credit_cardpmt">Credit card
</form>

<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `return false;` which blocks the selection

```js
$('.radio_pmt').click(function(){
alert('click'); 
var payment_mode =$(this).attr('ownid');

 var type = typeof payment_mode;
 if(payment_mode == 'undefined' | payment_mode == null){
  alert("Please select payment method");
 }
 else
 {
  if(payment_mode == "paypal")
  {
   $('input:radio[name="payment_mode"][ownid="paypal"]').attr('checked', true);
   $('input:radio[name="payment_mode"][ownid="paypal"]').val('paypal');
   $("#paypal_form").submit();
  }
  else
  {
   $('input:radio[name="payment_mode"][ownid="braintree"]').val('braintree');
   $('input:radio[name="payment_mode"][ownid="braintree"]').attr('checked');
   $("#braintree_details").slideDown("slow"); 
   
  }
 }
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="frm_choose_plan" name="frm_choose_plan">
<label>Choose Payment method:</label>
<input type="radio" class="radio_pmt" ownid="paypal" name="payment_mode" value="Paypal">Paypal
<input type="radio" class="radio_pmt" ownid="braintree"  name="payment_mode" value="braintree" id="credit_cardpmt">Credit card
</form>
```